# PDFKit / WKHTMLTOPDF not setting resolution on PDFs

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

PDFKit has been outputting pdfs that are shrunk—the content is in the top left corner, with whitespace filling the rest of the page.

I explicitly set the dpi and that fixed things on my local machine, but the server (AWS) is still showing the whitespace.

My config:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options = {
    encoding: 'UTF-8',
    disable_smart_shrinking: true,
    dpi: 384,
    page_width: '84.02cm',
    page_height: '118.8cm',
    margin_bottom: 0,
    margin_top: 0,
    margin_left: 0,
    margin_right: 0,
    orientation: 'Landscape'
  }
end
```

I looked at rightclick -> "more info" (Mac OSX) and on the correct pdf it shows

```
Resolution: 3367 x 2382
Content Creator: wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4
```

but neither of these fields are found in the bad pdf (with whitespace and shrunk content).

How do I get the resolution to be properly set in the pdf?

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of research—there's no real fix.

**The workaround is to set the page with px instead of cm**, then it doesn't matter what the dpi is, because the px of the page and the px of the css elements are using the same unit of measurement.

Comment: A thousand vote this .. i tried setting dpi, zoom, nothing worked.